# How do I use protogen with protobuf-net v2 beta?

Tags: protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I notice that the download for v2 beta does not include protogen, is this because the existing protogen-generated classes just work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Largely this simply a matter of validation / timing with the *beta*. There are also a number of tweaks logged in the code-gen area that I want to address, which I plan to address shortly.

However, there is a *functional* reason I haven't included it: by default (IIRC) it includes round-trip safe objects, using the unknown-fields API (extension fields). This feature is not in the current beta drop (you can do a vast amount without it).

If you don't request round-trip safe objects, the existing protogen should emit C# that is compatible with v2 (the entire v1 API is retained for both compatibility and convenience).